# Orbeon Forms: Read the Browser URL in Form Runner Mode

Tags: orbeon

How can I read the browser URL in Form Runner mode?

Many thanks in advance..

[See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Kg5.png)

I've tried using a few XXF: functions, but none appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you're looking for is `fr:form-runner-link()` ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-form-runner#fr-form-runner-link)).

It also takes as a parameter for you to say whether you'd like the link to take users to the page to create new data with this form, or to edit the current data, and more. This function is available since Orbeon Forms 2022.1, which, at the time of this writing, is planned for release in the next few weeks.

Comment: fr:form-runner-link() didnt work in the "initial value" formula when testing in Form Runner

Here's a test form: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/158147903246b51cd25874551e9d9f14e20615e1

Comment: Hi Pete, as I write this, the version of Orbeon Forms installed on demo is 2021.1.6, while this function is only available since 2022.1. If you have a PE subscription, please contact us through Basecamp, and we can send you a 2022.1 test build. Otherwise, you'll need to wait until the end of the year to be able to test this. -Alex